# Schengen visa - extention

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, berlin, visa-extensions

I have a schengen visa from Germany. My duration of stay is 30 days. I have been entered late on 14 august and my visa validity date is from 1 to 30 august.
Is this possible to stay for unused duration of stay? How is this possible?
I have found a website maybe it can help!
https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324785/en/

Comment: This would have been possible via the German consulate before you left.  Not after you enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website you found pretty much covers it, so I am at a loss to understand what you want to know. You need to contact the relevant *Ausländerbehörde* (if you are not in Berlin, Google “Ausländerbehörde + name of the place“) as soon as possible and provide all the documentation listed.

Note that, as stated on the website,

> An extension to a Schengen visa is only possible in exceptional cases where new facts and special reasons arise after entry.

The bit about late entry and unused stay is already stretching the rules, you are never entitled to an extension and certainly not to stay longer without having been formally allowed to do so. So you need to make an appointment/go to the foreigners' office and hand in your form soon enough to get an extension before August 30.

If you are not able to do this or the extension is refused, you have to leave. You can't simply stay in the Schengen area and count on your late entry to avoid any negative consequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to know is this possible in any Ausländerbehörde office or just in berlin?

Comment: @Amin The decision is up to the local Ausländerbehörde so you need to contact them. There are no guarantees and it's possible some are stricter than others because, as I said in the answer, you are not legally entitled to an extension in this situation.

Comment: @Amin I just understood that perhaps you meant your question differently. All Ausländerbehörde have the same function and are competent for a given territory. The Berlin website is among the best ones (and the only one I know that's completely translated in English) but other offices can also issue an extension. The rule is that the Berlin's office only deals with people who are currently in Berlin, etc. so not only could another office issue an extension if you meet their requirement but the one in Berlin should not deal with you if you are not in Berlin.

Comment: @Relaxed I have tried Weimar Ausländerbehörde and they told me that they don't do type c visas. So maybe I should go to the berlin office!!!

Comment: @Amin You could try another office in Thuringia at least, maybe in Erfurt (the capital city of the province). But I think the person might have misunderstood your request or be unaware of all this because extensions are very unusual. As I said, it's for exceptional circumstances, usually you simply cannot get a type C visa from within the country.